# sprng boot jpa + redis LazyInitializationException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-redis

I use spring boot 2.1.2 and redis as cache provider.

But now, I have a question.

1. In sysUser entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "sys_user")
@ToString(exclude = "roles")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class SysUser extends BaseEntity implements UserDetails {

    // ...

    /**
     * 当前用户的权限
     */
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "users")
    @JoinTable(name = "sys_user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)})
    private List<SysRole> roles;

    // ...
}
```

2. In sysRole entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "sys_role")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(exclude = {"users", "permissions"})
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class SysRole extends BaseEntity {

    // ...

    /**
     * 当前角色的菜单
     */
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "roles")
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "sys_permission_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id"))
    private List<SysPermission> permissions = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * 当前角色对应的用户
     * 双向映射造成数据重复查询死循环问题
     */
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private List<SysUser> users = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

3. In SysPermission entitty

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "sys_permission")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class SysPermission extends BaseEntity {
    // ...

    /**
     * 菜单角色
     * 双向映射造成数据重复查询死循环问题
     */
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "permissions")
    private List<SysRole> roles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

4. In sysUser service impl

```
    @Override
    @Cacheable
    public SysUser loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        return sysUserRepository.findFirstByUsernameAndEnabledTrue(username).orElseThrow(() ->
                new UsernameNotFoundException("用户不存在")
        );
    }
```

5. redis config

```
    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(12))
                .prefixKeysWith(applicationProperties.getName())
                .serializeKeysWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(keySerializer()))
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(valueSerializer()))
                .disableCachingNullValues();
        return RedisCacheManager
                .builder(RedisCacheWriter.nonLockingRedisCacheWriter(connectionFactory))
                .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration)
                .transactionAware()
                .build();
    }
    @Bean(name = "redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(keySerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(keySerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(valueSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(valueSerializer());
        return redisTemplate;
    }
    private RedisSerializer<String> keySerializer() {
        return new StringRedisSerializer();
    }
    private RedisSerializer<Object> valueSerializer() {
        return new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer();
    }
```

### Question

When I first called `loadUserByUsername`,it is ok.And in redis

[image: redis]

in json.cn

[image: json.cn]

But when I secound called `loadUserByUsername`,it is wrong,And get exception

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not read JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: cn.echocow.xiaoming.model.entity.SysUser["roles"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: cn.echocow.xiaoming.model.entity.SysUser["roles"])

    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:132)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:110)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.DefaultRedisElementReader.read(DefaultRedisElementReader.java:48)
......
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: cn.echocow.xiaoming.model.entity.SysUser["roles"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:353)
......
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:287)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:302)
......
```

[image: exception]

### Other

I try these methods

1. `@JsonIgnore` , but it will set `roles` is `null`, I want to use this field.
2. Config jackson registerModule `Hibernate5Module`, it will set `roles` is `null`.
3. Use `@Proxy(lazy = false)`, no changes.
4. Use `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`, no changes
5. config

```
spring:
  jpa:
    open-in-view: true
    properties
      hibernate:
        enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
```

no changes...

6. Use another json tools, such as gson and FastJson, but infinite loop for jpa when save cache.

Please help me, I had spent three days...But I do not resolve this question...

Thanks!

github address: [XIAOMING](https://github.com/lizhongyue248/xiaoming)

If do not have resolve method, maybe I must use Mybatis. But there is a lot of work.Please help me resolve this question...

Comment: Hi i have same issue
https://github.com/ripper2hl/sepomex/tree/redis-cache

Answer (score 4):

1st. create 2 classes below
The HibernateCollectionIdResolver.class will translate HibernateCollection class into JDK collection class, so the Jackson will write json from

```
{
    "paramA": [
    "org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet",
    []
  ]
}
```

to

```
{
    "paramA": [
    "java.util.HashSet",
    []
  ]
}
```

then the method typeFromId will get JDK JavaType from the class full name above, to deserialize your json to POJO.

```
class HibernateCollectionIdResolver extends TypeIdResolverBase {

    public HibernateCollectionIdResolver() {
    }

    @Override
    public String idFromValue(Object value) {
        //translate from HibernanteCollection class to JDK collection class
        if (value instanceof PersistentArrayHolder) {
            return Array.class.getName();
        } else if (value instanceof PersistentBag || value instanceof PersistentIdentifierBag || value instanceof PersistentList) {
            return List.class.getName();
        } else if (value instanceof PersistentSortedMap) {
            return TreeMap.class.getName();
        } else if (value instanceof PersistentSortedSet) {
            return TreeSet.class.getName();
        } else if (value instanceof PersistentMap) {
            return HashMap.class.getName();
        } else if (value instanceof PersistentSet) {
            return HashSet.class.getName();
        } else {
            //default is JDK collection
            return value.getClass().getName();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String idFromValueAndType(Object value, Class<?> suggestedType) {
        return idFromValue(value);
    }

    //deserialize the json annotated JDK collection class name to JavaType
    @Override
    public JavaType typeFromId(DatabindContext ctx, String id) throws IOException {
        try {
            return ctx.getConfig().constructType(Class.forName(id));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonTypeInfo.Id getMechanism() {
        return JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS;
    }
}
```

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS
)
@JsonTypeIdResolver(value = HibernateCollectionIdResolver.class)
public class HibernateCollectionMixIn {
}
```

2nd. register this MixIn class to you ObjectMapper

```
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
        mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        mapper.addMixIn(Collection.class, HibernateCollectionMixIn.class);
        jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.setObjectMapper(mapper);
```

last, register your jackson2JsonRedisSerializer to your RedisCacheConfiguration.

This would be helpful, I spent 2 days researching how to solve this problem.
And I found the json type id could be rewrite...
So just override jackson typeIdResolver~

EDIT: solve deserialization issue and add some comments

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @БогданОпир ok, and there's also some deserialize problems need to fix...

Comment: @beijiaxu This works for me so perfectly, can`t thank you more

Comment: Thank you! this took 2 days to find the issue.

Comment: @beijiaxu if you can answer the same here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77069997/unable-to-get-collection-from-redis-cache/77081189#77081189, I will award you the bounty

Answer (score 0):

In your code you return valueSerializer like this

```
 private RedisSerializer<Object> valueSerializer() {
    return new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer();
}
```

But you will have to return the GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer with Jackson Object mapper that has Hibernate5Module or Hibernate4Module registered as a module

```
public ObjectMapper getMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS);
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);

    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);

    // Registering Hibernate5Module to support lazy objects for hibernate 5
    // Use Hibernate4Module if using hibernate 4 
    mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());
    return mapper;
}


private RedisSerializer<Object> valueSerializer() {
    return new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(getMapper());
}
```