# How to fetch lazily initialized collection after fetching its parent collection from cache?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, redis

```
A{
Intger id;

String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
private B b;
}


B{
Integer id;

String name;
}
```

After the spring boot cache the object A upon calling findById (annotated by @Cacheable), when next time it is fetched from cache if the code a.getB().getId() runs then I receive the following error:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.freit.medicalservice.entity.B#1] - no Session
```

I tried the following solutions:

1. Used Hibernate.initalize(obj) [Also used Hibernate.isInitialized(obj) which returned true when before using Hibernate.initalize(obj)]
2. Used solution proposed by @beijiaxu on this thread [sprng boot jpa + redis LazyInitializationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54722546/sprng-boot-jpa-redis-lazyinitializationexception)
3. Saving the FETCH_TYPE.EAGER might solve the problem but I don't wanna use it.

Comment: You can try using EclipseLink for JPA which will allow fetching lazy mappings outside the context as long as the EMF is still open and accessible. Otherwise, and probably the best approach anyway is to fetch all the data you want to cache before caching it. You can pass in a fetch graph when loading your entity for the cache to ensure it is fetched before it is cached. You might want to look at caching each piece of the object graph separately, so that A is cached without references to B, and you use the bId value to search a cache for B directly

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Hibernate session is closed by the time you are trying to access the lazily loaded object, hence the exception.

Are you loading this collection of B conditionally? If yes then it makes sense to make it `LAZY` but if you are always loading it then you can consider loading it `EAGERLY`.

You can try calling `Hibernate.initialize(a.getB())` before accessing it from within the transaction to make it work.

Comment: It is already of LAZY fetch type, that is not solving the issue. I tried using hibernate.initialize(a.getB()) but got lazy initialization exception on this line of code too.

Comment: Can you try to load entity B from within the same transaction/session? You should get rid of the exception that way.

Also, why do you need a LAZY loading here? Why not fetch the records EAGERLY?

Comment: .get is working when I m calling it on the object which contains the row return by jpa query. .get does not work when I fetch the entity from cache and map it to jpa entity. Every one is missing the point here, instead of giving suggestions like use eagerly, transactional or anything give solution so I can initialize the referenced entity.