# Unable to get collection from Redis cache

Tags: spring, caching, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-cache

We are using Redis cache for storing data in cache in our application. We are directly using
@Cacheable to allow caching and using redis underneath to cache. Below is the config

Redis Config -

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RedisConfig implements CachingConfigurer {

@Value("${spring.cache.redis.time-to-live}")
Long redisTTL;

@Bean
public RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    objectMapper = objectMapper.copy();
    objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(objectMapper.getPolymorphicTypeValidator(), ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
    objectMapper.registerModules(new JavaTimeModule(), new Hibernate5Module())
            .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
            .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT)
            .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .entryTtl(Duration.ofDays(redisTTL))
            .disableCachingNullValues()
            .serializeKeysWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer()))
            .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper)));
}

@Bean
public RedissonClient reddison(@Value("${spring.redis.host}") final String redisHost,
                               @Value("${spring.redis.port}") final int redisPort,
                               @Value("${spring.redis.cluster.nodes}") final String clusterAddress,
                               @Value("${spring.redis.use-cluster}") final boolean useCluster,
                               @Value("${spring.redis.timeout}") final int timeout) {
    Config config = new Config();
    if (useCluster) {
        config.useClusterServers().addNodeAddress(clusterAddress).setTimeout(timeout);
    } else {
        config.useSingleServer().setAddress(String.format("redis://%s:%d", redisHost, redisPort)).setTimeout(timeout);
    }
    return Redisson.create(config);
}

@Bean
public RedissonConnectionFactory redissonConnectionFactory(RedissonClient redissonClient) {
    return new RedissonConnectionFactory(redissonClient);
}



@Bean
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(RedissonClient redissonClient, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    this.redissonConnectionFactory(redissonClient).getConnection().flushDb();
    RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager= RedisCacheManager.builder(this.redissonConnectionFactory(redissonClient))
            .cacheDefaults(this.cacheConfiguration(objectMapper))
            .build();
    redisCacheManager.setTransactionAware(true);
    return redisCacheManager;
}

@Override
public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
    return new RedisCacheErrorHandler();
}

@Slf4j
public static class RedisCacheErrorHandler implements CacheErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        log.info("Unable to get from cache " + cache.getName() + " : " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCachePutError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key, Object value) {
        log.info("Unable to put into cache " + cache.getName() + " : " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheEvictError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        log.info("Unable to evict from cache " + cache.getName() + " : " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheClearError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache) {
        log.info("Unable to clean cache " + cache.getName() + " : " + exception.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Service class -

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@Transactional
public class CompanyServiceImpl implements CompanyService {

private final CompanyRepository companyRepository;

@Cacheable(key = "#companyName", value = COMPANY_CACHE_NAME, cacheManager = "cacheManager")
public Optional<CompanyEntity> findByName(String companyName) {
    return companyRepository.findByName(companyName);
}

}
```

Company class -

```
@Entity    
@Jacksonized
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CompanyEntity  {

@Id
private Long id;

@ToString.Exclude
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "comapnyENtity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<EmployeeEntity> employeeEntities;

}
```

Once we run the service, caching gets done properly too. Once we fire the query, we get following record in cache -

```
> get Company::ABC
```

" {"@class":"com.abc.entity.CompanyEntity","createdTs":1693922698604,"id":100000000002,"name":"ABC","description":"ABC Operations","active":true,"EmployeeEntities":["org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag",[{"@class":"com.abc.entity.EmployeeEntity","createdTs":1693922698604,"Id":100000000002,"EmployeeEntity":{"@class":"com.abc.EmployeeLevel","levelId":100000000000,"name":"H1","active":true}}]]}"

> 

But while we try to execute the query the second time, it still goes inside the cache method with below logs -

```
    Unable to get from cache Company : Could not read JSON: failed to lazily initialize a 
    collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: 
    com.abc.entity.CompanyEntity$CompanyEntityBuilder["employeeEntities"]); nested exception 
    is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a c 
    collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: 
    com.abc.entity.CompanyEntity$CompanyEntityBuilder["employeeEntities"])
```

I understood from various SO answers that it is due unavailability of session for proxy child object. But we are caching using EAGER mode and whole collection is present in cache too. But still it goes inside the cached method and get values from db. How can we prevent it and use it directly from cache.

**UPDATE**
If we use LAZY loading, the collection objects doesn't get cached and comes as null. But we require cached collection as methods don't get call on order and cached method will return null later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the required answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62470778/2586617). My cache collection reference was not getting de-serialized properly. After applying the required changes, I was able to successfully de-serialize the cached collection object from Redis cache.

Changes in the existing Redis config -

```
@Bean
public RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    objectMapper = objectMapper.copy();
    objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
    objectMapper.registerModules(new JavaTimeModule(), new Hibernate5Module(), new Jdk8Module())
            .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
            .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT)
            .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY).addMixIn(Collection.class, HibernateCollectionMixIn.class);
    return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .entryTtl(Duration.ofDays(redisTTL))
            .disableCachingNullValues()
            .serializeKeysWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer()))
            .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper)));
}
```

Two new classes were added as part of the fix -

```
class HibernateCollectionIdResolver extends TypeIdResolverBase {

public HibernateCollectionIdResolver() {
}

@Override
public String idFromValue(Object value) {
    //translate from HibernanteCollection class to JDK collection class
    if (value instanceof PersistentArrayHolder) {
        return Array.class.getName();
    } else if (value instanceof PersistentBag || value instanceof PersistentIdentifierBag || value instanceof PersistentList) {
        return List.class.getName();
    } else if (value instanceof PersistentSortedMap) {
        return TreeMap.class.getName();
    } else if (value instanceof PersistentSortedSet) {
        return TreeSet.class.getName();
    } else if (value instanceof PersistentMap) {
        return HashMap.class.getName();
    } else if (value instanceof PersistentSet) {
        return HashSet.class.getName();
    } else {
        //default is JDK collection
        return value.getClass().getName();
    }
}

@Override
public String idFromValueAndType(Object value, Class<?> suggestedType) {
    return idFromValue(value);
}

//deserialize the json annotated JDK collection class name to JavaType
@Override
public JavaType typeFromId(DatabindContext ctx, String id) throws IOException {
    try {
        return ctx.getConfig().constructType(Class.forName(id));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public JsonTypeInfo.Id getMechanism() {
    return JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS;
}
```

}

And

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS
)
@JsonTypeIdResolver(value = HibernateCollectionIdResolver.class)
public class HibernateCollectionMixIn {
}
```

Comment: Can you illustrate then changes you had to make, when applied to your use case?

Answer (score 1):

A `JsonMappingException` means  [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson) is attempting to deserialize a Hibernate proxy object but is unable to do so because the Hibernate session is not available during deserialization.
So you need to ensure that the `employeeEntities` collection is properly initialized to a non-proxy state before serialization, in order for Jackson to correctly deserialize the `CompanyEntity` objects from the cache *without* requiring a Hibernate session.

You can ensure proper initialization of the collection by adjusting your service method to force the initialization of the `employeeEntities` collection before the `CompanyEntity` is cached!

```java
@Cacheable(key = "#companyName", value = COMPANY_CACHE_NAME, cacheManager = "cacheManager")
public Optional<CompanyEntity> findByName(String companyName) {
    Optional<CompanyEntity> companyEntityOpt = companyRepository.findByName(companyName);
    companyEntityOpt.ifPresent(companyEntity -> {
        companyEntity.getEmployeeEntities().size();  // Force initialization of the collection
    });
    return companyEntityOpt;
}
```

That way, the `employeeEntities` collection is converted from a Hibernate proxy to a regular Java collection. That should help to avoid the `JsonMappingException` you are experiencing during deserialization from the cache.

This assumes you are using [`FetchType.EAGER`](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading#Loading), meaning the `employeeEntities` collection is being loaded automatically when you fetch a `CompanyEntity`.

---

If the issue persists, you can check if detaching the entity help:

```java
@Cacheable(key = "#companyName", value = COMPANY_CACHE_NAME, cacheManager = "cacheManager")
public Optional<CompanyEntity> findByName(String companyName) {
    Optional<CompanyEntity> companyEntityOpt = companyRepository.findByName(companyName);
    companyEntityOpt.ifPresent(companyEntity -> {
        companyEntity.getEmployeeEntities().size();  // Force initialization of the collection
        // Obtain entity manager and detach the entity
        EntityManager em = // get entity manager bean
        em.detach(companyEntity);
    });
    return companyEntityOpt;
}
```

Detaching the entity from the Hibernate session would to turn it into a normal POJO.

Note that to get the `EntityManager` you will need to inject it into your service class, and you should ensure that all relationships and attributes that will be accessed later are properly initialized before detaching the entity.

---

The other approach, to avoid caching Hibernate managed entities directly or ensure that Hibernate proxies are not serialized is to use DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) to separate your persistence model from the objects you are working with in the application logic.

- Create a DTO class that corresponds to your `CompanyEntity` class.
- Before caching, map your `CompanyEntity` instance to a DTO instance.
- Cache the DTO instance instead of the entity instance.
- When reading from the cache, you will get a DTO instance which you can then map back to an entity instance if necessary.

In your service class, it would look something like this:

```java
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@Transactional
public class CompanyServiceImpl implements CompanyService {

    private final CompanyRepository companyRepository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper; // Bean for mapping entity to DTO

    @Cacheable(key = "#companyName", value = COMPANY_CACHE_NAME, cacheManager = "cacheManager")
    public Optional<CompanyDTO> findByName(String companyName) {
        Optional<CompanyEntity> companyEntityOpt = companyRepository.findByName(companyName);
        return companyEntityOpt.map(companyEntity -> {
            companyEntity.getEmployeeEntities().size(); // Force initialization of the collection
            return modelMapper.map(companyEntity, CompanyDTO.class); // Map entity to DTO before caching
        });
    }
}
```

In this method, you would use a `ModelMapper` or another mapping framework to map your entity to a DTO. That DTO would be what gets cached, avoiding the Hibernate proxy issues you are experiencing.

Remember to create a corresponding DTO for `EmployeeEntity` and any other entities that are part of your object graph.

That approach would require creating additional classes and modifying your service logic but it will create a clean separation between your Hibernate entities and what gets cached, which can help avoid issues like this one.

Comment: hello Von, sorry. with above force check too, same exception is there.

Comment: hello @Vonc, above suggestions looks correct but above answer worked for me. I have posted an answer.